Allow a user to select which date column to filter on
I am working on a new Power BI report and need to solve the how to let users dynamically pick which date to filter on.
The Data is
Order Id, Sales Date, Invoice Received Date, Amount
I want the users to have a filter that they can select Sales Date or Invoice Received Date Last Quarter.
I found this and got selecting the range of values working Dynamic Date Filter based on end-user choice but I want a hard coded Last Quarter instead of a user selectable range of values.
